# Different volume results in QGIS by using Raster Surface Volume and raster statistics

Tags: qgis, statistics, volume, surface

I have seen many questions similar to mine, but did not find an answer to my problem. I am using QGIS version 3.28.11-Firenze.

I have a raster representing the difference between two DEMs on a fluvial plain, where each pixel represents the elevation change between two time steps. I want to calculate the volume of the positive and negative pixels, so to know how much material has been deposited and how much has been removed. Values of the raster range between -4m and +4m circa.
I tried two options (the DoD - DEM of Difference - is clipped to the desired area of interest so that there are no NoData values):

1. I extracted the positive and negative pixels by using the raster calculator (using a threshold of >0.2 for the positive ones, and <-0.2 for the negative ones - this is related to the error of acquisition of the original data). I then calculated the Raster Layer Statistics (in the Raster Analysis toolbox) of each new raster. The sum of the negative pixel is -8298.5834, which also corresponds to the volume because the DoD is at 1m resolution. The sum of the positive pixel is 6366.9661.
2. I used the Raster Surface Volume tool in the Raster Analysis toolbox and calculate the volume above and below the same thresholds (0.2, and -0.2) as base level and got -6141.9834 m3 for the negative value and 4265.3661 m3 for the positive one. The pixel count for the negative area is 10783 (also the area in m2 because the DoD is at 1m resolution), whereas for the positive area the pixel count is 10508.

Why do the two methods gave me so large differences?

To have an independent method, I calculate the volumes in Matlab and got a negative volume of -8298.5834 with number of pixel = 10783, and a positive volume of 6366.9661 with a number of pixel = 10508.

Any idea?